# Android open activity from fragment showing two screen separately

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have created an app. which contains MainActivity->inside fragments class loading with some UI works..
After I have tried to pass some datas to new Library Activity (inside one fragment available with make some works and need to get back result.)

Problem: when i open new activity, its showing two separate apps like..
starting Activity Page and Library Activity.. But, after entered library activity, finish the work and get back result to MainActivity Successfully..

Note: Even, Library Activity showing as a seperate App. thats my problem.

Please help..Thanks for Advance

Comment: have you tried with onActivityResult???

Comment: Simply apply fragment instead of Activity can help you with your problem